# How to make the steps to be 6 hours in a sliderInput in R

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

# ui.R

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Initial run of time range update breaks sliderInput',
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 100, 
           sliderInput("timeRange", label = "Time range",
                       min = as.POSIXct("2011-06-04 12:00:00"),
                       max = as.POSIXct("2011-08-10 14:00:00"),
                       value = c(as.POSIXct("2011-06-04 12:00:00"),
                                 as.POSIXct("2011-08-10 14:00:00"))),
           actionButton("update", "Update range")

    )
  )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$from <- renderText(input$timeRange[1]);
  output$to <- renderText(input$timeRange[2]);
  observe({
    input$update;
    updateSliderInput(session, "timeRange", value = 
                        c(as.POSIXct("2011-06-14 
          12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-08-01 14:00:00")));
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui,server = server))
```

The above is the code. I want to make the slider such that each step will result in a 6 hour increase or decrease.

What do I set the "step" parameter of the sliderInput function to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the [step for a POSIXt object](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html) is in seconds.

So I guess 6 hours = 6 * 60 * 60 = 21600 ?